# Access to fetch at $AWS_LAMBDA_SITE from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-lambda, single-page-application

Using ExpressJs and ClaudiaJs I have published a web server to AWS Lambda. This server's job is to process Stripe payments. I am trying to get my React SPA to submit the Stripe checkout from the client, but am receiving a CORS error when I try to submit.

How can I avoid this CORS error? I would imagine I need to either publish both client and AWS server on the same TLD (not sure how to make that work), or I'd need to disable CORS on the server (but that seems insecure).

Stripe server call:

```
    this.handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: test_key,
        locale: "auto",
        mode: "no-cors",
        name: "Company 1234",
        description: "donation",
        token: token => {
            // Send the donation to your server
            console.log("server pinged");

            fetch(`${backendUrl}/charge`, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    stripeToken: token,
                    chargeAmount: this.state.donationAmount
                })
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(json => {
                    console.log("response is " + json);
                    this.setState({ donationResponse: "Thank you for donating!" });
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.setState({
                        donationResponse:
                            "There was an issue processing your request. Please try again later"
                    });
                });
        }
    });
```

Form submission

```
formSubmit = async event => {
    console.log("form submitted");
    event.preventDefault();

    const amount = this.state.donationAmount * 100; // Needs to be an integer in cents
    this.handler.open({
        amount: Math.round(amount)
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass origin header in request from your local app. And in response from AWS lambda you can add below response headers :

```
headers :{
    "access-control-allow-origin": "localhost",
    "access-control-allow-credentials": "true"
}
```

In lambda environment variables, you can configure list of allowed origin separated by comma(,) to ensure only legitimate domain are getting access. something like below:

```
 "localhost, yourdomain.com"
```

The CORS issue is really around browser blocking request for other domain, which can be solved by adding above headers.

I also have faced similar issue, where we had request routed through apigateway -- lambda.

Comment: This was a big help. I have added `mode: "no-cors"` to my fetch request, and `var cors = require("cors");app.use(cors());
app.options("*", cors()); // include before other routes` to my server initialization in expressjs. 
The error disappears and the server can respond. 
However, now my request body is empty. No matter what I do it stays empty, any idea what that might be from? FYI I am also using `body-parser` via `app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

Comment: Issue solved here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214229/expressjs-request-body-is-empty