# ExpressJs request body is empty

Tags: node.js, express, cors, fetch

I have an express app at `localhost:5000` and a react app at `localhost:3000`.

I am calling it via

```
            fetch(`${backendUrl}/charge`, {
                method: "POST",
                mode: "no-cors",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: {
                    stripeToken: token,
                    chargeAmount: this.state.donationAmount
                }
            })
```

And responding with

```
function route(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
}
```

Server should be properly configured to work with CORS, but the body is still empty.

```
//configure env variables
require("dotenv").config();

//import packages
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cors = require("cors");

//import route functions
const StripeRoute = require("./StripeRoute");

//setup app
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//setup bodyparser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//Setup CORS
app.use(cors());
app.options("*", cors()); // include before other routes

//Connect functions to API routes
app.post("/charge", StripeRoute);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: the express route , in its args , needs to include a ref to instance/obj of the body-parser in use.

Comment: Good idea. I tried `const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
app.post("/charge", jsonParser, StripeRoute);` but it didn't help. I believe the `app.use` statements automagically make the parser work universally, so it doesn't need to be passed into each route

Comment: @JamesL. that's correct (`app.use(bodyParser.json())` will enable JSON body parsing for each request)

Comment: Ok great! Thanks for the confirmation. Here's the doc - https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use - I'm surprised there's no `path` argument to `app.use`. Somehow it just figures out when to use `json` or `urlencoded`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Body), the `body` option should be one of a few specific types, `Object` not being one of them.

Try using a JSON string:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
  stripeToken: token,
  chargeAmount: this.state.donationAmount
})
```

**EDIT**: because you're using `no-cors`, you can't set `Content-Type application/json`. Instead, you need to generate a URL-encoded string and set `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (because `no-cors` will only work using "simple headers", as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode) and further).

Comment: Good call. I turned off stringify when testing and forgot to add it back in. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Have you checked what's being sent in the request using your browser's dev tools?

Comment: Before it was just reading `[object Object]` but now it reads `{chargeAmount: 1
stripeToken: {id: "tok_1DUIwAKyncO2gMGh5rzh1hpZ", object: "token",…}
card: {id: "card_1DUIwAKyncO2gMGhcEpYyocx", object: "card", address_city: null, address_country: null,…}
client_ip: "173.244.44.49"
created: 1541704386
email: "asd@asd.asd"
id: "tok_1DUIwAKyncO2gMGh5rzh1hpZ"
livemode: false
object: "token"
type: "card"
used: false
}` IDK what changed

Comment: The latter looks okay to me (the reason you got `[object Object]` is because of `Object` not being a valid option value for `body`, and it just gets stringified). Try running your server using `DEBUG=* node server.js` (or whatever it's called), perhaps it may shed some light on why the body isn't being parsed correctly. With your code and a similar Express setup, I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Good idea! I found how to start express in debug mode here - https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html. It looks like it's using the wrong encoder? `express:router dispatching POST /charge +17s
  express:router query  : /charge +2ms
  express:router expressInit  : /charge +1ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /charge +1ms
  express:router urlencodedParser  : /charge +1ms
  express:router corsMiddleware  : /charge +0ms
{}
Request missing all parameters`

Comment: Yeah it looks like the JSON parser is passing on the request. Back to your browser's dev tools: what are the request headers that are being sent? Is `content-type` correct?

Comment: It's `Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8`!!! My fetch explicitly asks it to be json,`headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
     },` What could be going wrong?

Comment: Oh, hang on, you're running this in a browser! Which means that using `no-cors`, you can't set `content-type` to `application/json`. You need to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and URL-encode the `body` option value.

Comment: It works! Almost, kind of. Express console is printing `{ '$JSON_STRINGIFIED':''}`. Is this the expected output of body-parser? Great catch, tho this restriction seems a bit arbitrary (without knowing more about it at least) EDIT - I think this is because I'm not encoding the body right, BRB

Comment: I have no idea where that's from. The restriction is mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode) (well, it links to  a page regarding "simple headers", where it is actually explained).

Comment: After doing some research it looks like I just may be out of luck due to the `ContentType` I have to use, and I need to extract and parse that key to get the JSON. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388507/the-json-data-in-request-body-is-not-getting-parsed-using-body-parser https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/263